# CSS3 3D transformed div gets cropped by three.js canvas on iOS & OSX Safari

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, gsap

I'm working on a three.js based site and used HTML divs over the three.js canvas to display menus and info.
But I discovered that the 3D trasnformed div gets sliced on a weird way by the three.js canvas on iOS browsers and OSX safari. 
On chrome and Firefox (osx) works as intended.

I set a codepen that illustrate the problem with the basic cube example of the three.js library.
http://codepen.io/theguaz/pen/jrGvPX

```
<--------HTML----------->

<body>
<div id="hitosMenu">

                <ul id="hitosMenu-ul">
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="0"><p>01. CALLE MARCO AURELIO</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="1"><p>02. ESCALERA BOCACCIO</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="2"><p>03. FARO AZUL</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="3"><p>04. PLAZA BISMARCK</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="4"><p>05.ATAHUALPA</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="5"><p>06. SALTO HOTEL</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="6"><p>07. CALLE ELÍAS</p><p>SALTO</p></li>
                    <li class="hitosItem" dataID="7"><p>08. PERGOLA/META</p><p>SALTO</p></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
</body>


<--------CSS------->

body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#hitosMenu{
  position:absolute;
    width:450px;
    height:450px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:a='http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/' width='587.6px' height='622.8px' xml:space='preserve'> <polygon id='XMLID_1_' opacity='0.9' fill='%23001A71' points='102.6,0 587.6,0 483.7,622.8 0,622.8 '/> </svg>")  no-repeat;
    background-size:400px;
    background-position: 0px 0px; 

}

ul#hitosMenu-ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    width:65%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul#hitosMenu-ul li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


ul#hitosMenu-ul li p:nth-child(1){
    height:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul#hitosMenu-ul li p:nth-child(1){
    font-family: "RedBullSiri-Black",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;

    color:#999966;
}

ul#hitosMenu-ul li p:nth-child(2){
    font-family: "futura-pt",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;

    font-size: 10px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffcd10;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    color:#FFFFA9;

}

<--------JS------>


  var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mesh;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.z = 400;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 400, 400, 400 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );
  mesh.position.x = 0;
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }
var hitosOrig = "50% 50%";
TweenMax.to($("#hitosMenu"), .55, {delay:.35, css:{autoAlpha:.85,  transformOrigin:hitosOrig, transformPerspective:-1000, rotationY:-16}});
```

What I could be doing wrong?.

Comment: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );`may work.

Comment: @WestLangley, thank's for the reply; but it did not worked at all, not in the real project and neither on the codepen, you can see the updated codepen and check it out.

Comment: You must pass `alpha` as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: weird stuff, I did passed the parameter on the constructor, but I get the cut at the center of the transformation of the div anyway.

https://d.pr/ZsvG

Comment: @WestLangley I tried various ways to set the alpha value of the renderer, and on all of them It does set the alpha of the canvas, but the 3D transformed canvas still gets cropped on safari and mobile.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: @WestLangley hi, today I reviewed the alternative of using CSS3DObjects, so maybe I could insert my problematic div into the three.js and trys to solve the problem.
I've set a simple example here http://codepen.io/theguaz/pen/kkZQLB and then realized that  CSS3DObjects also were working oddly on Safari and iOS browsers.

Comment: @mrdoob maybe has an opinion on this.

Comment: @WestLangley the aproach of inseting the problematic div into three.js finally did results that worked well :)
http://codepen.io/theguaz/pen/wzyNAQ
Finally I'm happy, thank's a lot for your comments and help.

Comment: Yay! ----------